# How can i optimize this javascript code (Spreadsheet getelementid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I've been using a *js*-code to access to a *Google Spreadsheet API*, in which I can change any cell and the value will change after a refresh.

The site is build with *Elementor* and what I want to do is to use **one single source link** `<script src="spreadsheetlink">` in the entire page, instead of using it in every single element.

Right now, the setup is the following:

Snippet in the footer with this code

```
<script>
var onDataLoaded = (data) => {
  const b1Content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'B1').content.$t
  document.getElementById('menulh').innerHTML = b1Content
}
</script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BJejAeuUJPK76M4cEcqZvOqWiuvO4zQMusWBCMacgCI/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded"></script>
```

And every html element I add to *Elementor* is like this

```
<p style="display:inline-block;font-weight:600">
  <a style="color:black" id="zpp"></a>
</p>
<script>
  var onDataLoaded = (data) => {
    const a4content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'A4').content.$t
    document.getElementById('zpp').innerHTML = a4content
  }
</script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BJejAeuUJPK76M4cEcqZvOqWiuvO4zQMusWBCMacgCI/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded"></script>
```

If I wanted to duplicate the page, I would have to change every spreadsheet link in every element, what I want is to have only one source in the page and the elements grab it from there.

This is the site I'm taking about:
[tomasperren.com.ar/prueba](https://tomasperren.com.ar/pruebas/)

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what the `elementor` is, and don't know how do you add scripts to the page. It's even possible that you're doing it by hand for each item on the page. Can't help you with that without seeing your code.

And I'm not sure what you're trying to optimize exactly:

- your speed
- code's speed
- code's size
- etc., etc.
  ?

But one thing is for sure: instead of

```
<script>
 var onDataLoaded = (data) => {
   const a4content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'A4').content.$t
    document.getElementById('zpp').innerHTML = a4content
 }
</script>
...
<script>
 var onDataLoaded = (data) => {
   const a4content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'C4').content.$t
    document.getElementById('zxpp').innerHTML = a4content
 }
</script>
...
```

your can write

```
<script>
 var makeFuncOnDataLoaded = (id, cell) => (data) => {
   const a4content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == cell).content.$t
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = a4content
 }
</script>
...
<script>
 var onDataLoaded = makeFuncOnDataLoaded('zpp', 'A4')
</script>
...
<script>
 var onDataLoaded = makeFuncOnDataLoaded('zxpp', 'C4')
</script>
...
```

### Update

After some thought I can guess (but that's only a guess) that you need to replace all your scripts with this:

```
<script>
  var onDataLoaded = (data) => {
    const id_to_cells_mapping = [
      [ 'menulh': 'B1' ],
      [ 'zpp', 'A4' ],
      [ 'zxpp', 'C4' ],
      ...
    ]
    id_to_cells_mapping.forEach(([id, cell]) => {
      const a4content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t === cell).content.$t
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = a4content
    })
  }
</script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1BJejAeuUJPK76M4cEcqZvOqWiuvO4zQMusWBCMacgCI/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=onDataLoaded"></script>
```

and put it in the `<head>`

Comment: After I've edited your question I started to understand what you want, but I need more info to update my answer... But don't really know what kind of info. I'm not familiar with *Elementor* and have too many questions :)

Comment: Also I don't understand... Aren't you loading the whole `data.feed` for each item on the page, Shouldn't you instead load the `feed` only once on page load?